# Web2Py - Python Syntax

Tags: python, syntax, web2py

I recently began working with Web2Py, after a long period of learning Python. As a beginner, I'm used to having modules and knowing their attributes to getting my work done. For example, I can import the time module and look up the time.sleep() function in the existing documentation to see how I can employ it the way I see fit.

Web2Py, however, employs a lot of Python code that, while easy on the eyes and relatively straightforward if you take the time to study it, isn't exactly covered in detail in the manual. For instance, I occasionally see a response.something in the code, and I can't find the details of the response function anywhere; or I'll see a URL pop up in curly brackets which references a file in, say, my static folders that has syntax like `{{=URL(r = "request", c = 'static', f = 'image.png')}}` with no explanations of the various attributes of the URL call anywhere in the manual. The manual appears to cover only the aspects of configuring the MVCs and doing specific tasks.

What I'm trying to say is: is there a python.org type documentation for all the exceptional Python functions that appear in Web2Py code?

I'll be much obliged. Thanks!

Comment: `response` is a Storage object, not a function. Anyway, both `response` and the `URL()` helper function are fairly well documented in the book. Granted, some things are missing from the documentation, but overall it is fairly comprehensive. If you want more detail regarding function signatures, class structures, etc., you can check out the [Epydoc](http://www.web2py.com/examples/static/epydoc/index.html) source code documentation, or of course, just browse the source code itself.

Answer (score 1):

These are covered in [chapter 4 of the web2py book](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04)

[response](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04#response)

[URL](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04#URL)

Comment: Please refrain from adding link only answers. If the links break, the answer becomes useless to future visitors. Could you add the relevant information to your answer and reference it with the links?

Comment: @Ren, I agree. Though this question is asking _where_ the documentation is, and it not very specific. In this case the official docs are the best place to start and I don't there is much point pasting the entire book here either.

Comment: My bad, I stopped reading the question before the last two paragraphs. Yeah, I opened the links and there is quite a lot of information there and there would likely be copyright issues with copying that much text across anyway.

Comment: I must not have seen it the last time I was perusing the manual. Thanks for bringing this to my attention!